# Problemas con el Calendario DatePicker de JQuery-UI, se queda abierto al establecer un setDate al cargar mi página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

Estoy usando la función `datepicker()` de `JQuery-UI` y la he programado para que al cargar mi pagina me muestre la fecha actual en un input `HTML`.

**Código JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#fecha-ticket").datepicker({
changeMonth:true,
changeYear: true,
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
$("#fecha-ticket").datepicker("hide");

$('#iconoCal').click(function() {
$("#fecha-ticket").focus();
});

});
```

La fecha se muestra en el input como debiera de ser:

[image: Imagen del Input y setDate]

Pero al momento de hacer lo anterior deja abierto el calendario en la parte inferior de mi pagina.

[image: Datepicker sin Cerrar]

Lo que quisiera saber es ¿Cómo o de qué Manera puedo mostrar la fecha actual sin que se quede abierto el `datepicker`?

> Ya intente usar: `datepicker( "hide" )`

Comment: Estoy seguro de que si abres la consola del navegador, encontrarás algún error que para la ejecución de tu código y, por tanto, impide que el widget se cierre correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Honestamente la informacion que nos brindas es muy poca para resolver tu error pero considero que utilizar esta etiqueta en lugar de datepicker() podria solventar tu problema. Solamente agregas los css de bootstrap y no habrá problema

```js
$(document).ready(function(){         
  var now = new Date();

  var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

  var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

  $('#date').val(today);
});
```

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Título de la página</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <input id="date" type="date" val="now">
    </BODY>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</HTML>
```